# PlayN canvas.drawText() weird behaviour in HTML (Java is ok)

Tags: playn

I want to use the canvas.drawText() method to draw some text frame after frame. When I run my game in Java, everything is fine. But when I run in html, the behaviour is different. I isolated the code (see below) and I get the same result.

```
package textbug.core;

import static playn.core.PlayN.*;

import playn.core.Canvas;
import playn.core.CanvasImage;
import playn.core.Game;
import playn.core.Image;
import playn.core.ImageLayer;

public class TextBugIsolated implements Game {

    Canvas canvas;
    int x = 20;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    // create and add background image layer
    Image bgImage = assetManager().getImage("images/bg.png");
    ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);

    CanvasImage canvasImage = graphics().createImage(graphics().width(), graphics().height());

    ImageLayer imageLayer = graphics().createImageLayer();
    imageLayer.setImage(canvasImage);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(imageLayer);

    canvas = canvasImage.canvas();    
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(float alpha) {
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.drawText("PlayN is cool!", x++, 20);
    canvas.drawText("Hello World", 20, 100);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(float delta) {
  }

  @Override
  public int updateRate() {
    return 25;
  }
}
```

I would expect the text "PlayN is cool!" to move horizontally like in Java but it is not. I tried to debug but I cannot step in the native code.

Anyone has a clue? Am I trying something prohibited?

Comment: I forgot to mention I tested on Chrome. I also tested with Safari but this time there was no text at all.

Comment: I have the same problem with canvas.drawImage... No image on screen :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/playn/issues/detail?id=85). It only affects the HTML backend. That seems to be exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.

Do you wait for the image to load, because the case in safari is maybe it loads after the drawText and paints over it.. and in java probably the loading is fast enough so it loads fine.

care for the  done() callback ... so it sets the text update after the image is loaded

Comment: Even if I remove the image, the text does not move. It looks like it's a problem with the Canvas class.

Comment: I also had some wierd canvas.clear() problems.. can you please remove it... do not clear anything just draw over it... and write back.. ill look more clearly in your code